# Specific .exe gives error when launched through PowerShell start-process [powershell]

Tags: powershell

I am trying to launch an .exe through powershell using the following code

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Varian\MPC\2.20\VMS.MPC.Application.exe"
```

and I get the following error message:
"An unexpected error occured occured. Please restart MPC. If the problem persists, please contact service." (MPC is the software I am trying to launch)

Launching this specific executable either through directly clicking on it or on a desktop shortcut works fine.

Launching other executables through start-process works fine, just tried with Acrobat Reader.

What could be preventing it from launching through PowerShell start-process command?
I am using windows 7 with powershell version 2.0.

Comment: What happens if you don't use the desktop shortcut, but click directly on the executable? The desktop shortcut probably adds some necessary arguments. You might check on that.

Comment: Clicking on the executable directly also launches the software normally.

Comment: Try to add `-Wait` to the `Start-Process` cmdlet. Does it help?

Comment: Adding -wait had no effect.

Comment: PLEASE, post your code AS CODE, not as an image. why force those who want to help to squint/zoom just to read your code that you _already have as text_?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey done!

Comment: @aggelosv - thank you! i appreciate it ... and can easily read it now. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look on desktop shortcut (properties) to obtain two informations :

1) Launch parameters.

2) The working directory.

Try start-proces adding `-WorkingDirectory`.

Comment: @Thomas thanks, would that answer my follow-up question below?

Answer (score 0):

@JPBlanc 's suggestion did the trick, I used

```
Start-Process -FilePath "VMS.MPC.Application.exe" -WorkingDirectory "C:\Program Files (x86)\Varian\MPC\2.20\"
```

and it worked! Now I am a bit confused though. Why does

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 11.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe"
```

launch Acrobat reader just fine, but the following fails to launch the MPC software

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Varian\MPC\2.20\VMS.MPC.Application.exe"
```

Comment: It appends that you read the config file in the current directory.